# can you use an expression inside of NG-MODEL?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I want to use a an expression inside of an NG-MODEL directive Is there a way to accomplish this binding?  can it be done using something like compile? here is my markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div></div>
    <range min="0" max="100" model="width"></range>
</body>
</html>
<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>


<script>

var app = angular.module("pager", []);

app.run(function($rootScope){

    console.log($rootScope);    

});

angular.element(document).ready(function(){

    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector("html"), ["pager"]);

})

app.directive("range", function ($compile) {

    return {

        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope:{

            min:"@",
            max:"@",
            model:"@"

        },
        template: "<input type='range' ng-model='{{model}}' value='0' min='{{min}}' max='{{max}}'/>",

    }

})
</script>
```

ng-model='{{model}}' gives you an error is there a way to get it read the model attribute from the directive?  Is that possible to link it that way or do i have to use $compile to accomplish this.  I want my directives to be able to create variables in the child scope then bind it to the ng-model that the directive is generating. I want to use the attribute of "model" from the directive to create the variable for the ng-model.  in this example I want "width" to be where the {{model}} expression is.

Comment: Why do you even have this directive? Just to save a little typing? You don't need to interpolate model. Remove the {{}}.

Comment: I want to make it re-usable I am not sure what the best way to do it is honestly I am at a little bit of an intermediate level with Angular, whats the best way to pass that variable model and make it equal to "width"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

If you replace the `@` with the `=` than you will see it on your controller `$scope` (without using an expression), take a look at the below code and fiddle.

**Edit**

```
app.directive("range", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            min: "@",
            max: "@",
            model: '='
        },
        compile: function () {
            return {
                pre: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    // The directives isolated scope
                    console.log(scope);
                    // Controller scope
                    console.log(scope.$parent);
                }
            }
        },
        template: "<input type='range' ng-model='model' value='0' min='{{min}}' max='{{max}}'/>"
    }
});
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/kQ2rX/1/)</kbd>

Comment: that definetly helps but I the reason for the model attribute, is I want `model = width` to be bound to `$scope.width` in the controller that way I can map it and re-use the directive, I want add range input that has a model of model="height" and it map to the $scope.height and so on, would scope:{model:"&"} make more sense.  I am still learning how to work with Isolate Scope and child scopes

Comment: @Jesse - you can reuse the directive - inside the directive it will be bound to model, but in your controller, `<range min="0" max="100" model="width"></range>` the model will still be bound to `$scope.width` - they are both referencing the same object, just calling it something else.

Comment: thank you will work try that too see what will work best

Comment: @jesse I'm not sure that I follow. My sample does have the `width` bound in the controllers scope, that's why I have the log scope button. [Here is a more complex fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/kQ2rX/3/) showing `height` and `width` and how they can be used with `ng-style`. Also these attr's can still be accessed within your directive, either through `link` or `compile`.

Comment: thanks Asok thats exactly what I was trying to do I just need to rework the code a bit to make it a little more re-usable I have about 10 different thins I need to have bind like width, height, border-radius, color etc...